# How do I cache files on disk, deleting old files when folder size too large?

Tags: c++, linux, caching

I'm creating a program that converts files between formats as a service. It should cache the resultant files in case the same conversion is requested again. Hence I need to store files on disk in such a way that they the oldest one is deleted when the folder size exceeds a given amount.

I'm looking for a C / C++ library or even a separate binary or linux function (similar to logrotate) that would do this. It seems like something that must have been done before. The program will be running on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Each time you need to store a new cache, check the size of caches-folder and remove the oldest one. You can handle everything via software. The date of a cache can be stored as *hash table* or read with a system-call by OS file's properties.

Comment: Well yes, I've written my own one now, but I was looking for a ready made library. Seems like I'm reinventing the wheel a bit here.